# Does link.exe have an equivalent to ld's "--wrap" option?

Tags: c++, linker

For reference, I'm looking for something that behaves similarly to this:

> --wrap=symbol Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to "__wrap_symbol". Any
>   undefined reference to "__real_symbol" will be resolved to symbol.

Does such a thing exist for link.exe? I didn't see anything stick out on the MSDN linker page.

EDIT: My dev environment doesn't support DLLs, so a DLL only solution won't help here.

Comment: As far as I know it doesn't. This thread contains some discussions on a similar topic that might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316018/globally-override-malloc-in-visual-c

Comment: Thanks for the link. A combination of /nodefaultlib, defining my own symbols, and linking to crt directly might do the trick. I'll have to mess around with this.

Answer (score 1):

Tricky but possible for DLL's. Your DLL should implement `wrap_symbol` and link with a `.DEF` file which renames it to `symbol`. You can call the original function from within your DLL as just `symbol()`, as the renaming of `wrap_symbol` happens later.

Comment: I should clarify that this is for console development. We don't use DLLs since they negatively affect our load times and performance (we lose /ltcg support).

Comment: Oh, the `/LTCG` part is even more important than you probably realized. Your libs don't contain the assembly for `symbol`, but its (preprocessed) code. BTW, seems GCC has an open issue on `-flto --wrap` for similar reasons.